# What is the term for a whistle done with two fingers in mouth

Tags: word-choice, terminology

Is there an English term that describes the whistle you'd make with two fingers/one finger and thumb in your mouth? Maybe those variations have separate names. Googling got me *[wolf whistle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf-whistling)* but that looks like it's specifically about a two-note thing and not so as much about the putting hands in mouth format. Also there is a kind of expressing lasciviousness vibe which is not what I'm after.

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Whistle-With-Your-Fingers doesn't look like there's a single word.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm not looking for a single word necessarily, just a canonical way to express it.

Comment: About all I've ever heard is "two-finger whistle".

Comment: @Mari-LouA Hmmm. Not as catchy as I'd have imagined but for sure descriptive. I'll accept that if you'd want to post it as an answer.

Comment: I've heard it called "cattle-whistle", but that could just be because I'm from Texas.

Comment: @HotLicks "two finger whistle" is good, but in the UK at least risks being confused with "the V sign" https://stronglang.wordpress.com/2015/10/08/up-yours-the-gesture-that-divides-america-and-the-uk/ which is sometimes referred to as a "two-finger salute".  Regardless I still think it gets the point across better than anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also looked this up and like others have said I've only found "finger whistling" according to Wikipedia or simply "whistling with your fingers."
[Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whistling#Techniques)